# Xamarin.Forms make non-transparent overlay not clickable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, overlay

I have this XAML

```
<ContentPage>
     <RelativeLayout>
          <ScrollView />
          <Button />
          <local:ModalActivityIndicator />
     </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This indicator is relative to its parent and covers it's full width and height.
The indicator has this binding: `this.SetBinding (IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy");`
It is showing precisely how I want it, but I can still tap on items in the `ScrollView` and on the `Button`.
When the indicator shows, the `InputTransparent` property is set to `false`.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This could be a bug in `Xamarin.Forms`. in which case you will need to file a bug report at [https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/). To me your code looks correct

Comment: How would I know this is a bug and not a misinterpretation from my side? Can I just file the bug and see what happens?

Comment: That is a good question and there's never a correct answer. Ususally if you look at your code and it looks to be correct and it isnt working as expected you can file a bug. Also look through previous bug reports and see if anyone has already filed something similar. Another way is to test on different platforms and see if it behaves differently and if it does at least one of the platforms has a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather acceptable workaround for this.
If you add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `ModalActivityIndicator`, all input will be caught by the overlay and no interaction will be transferred to the underlying elements.

`GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer());`